# Anyone try knockoutJS with Coldbox Coldfusion? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, coldfusion

I am ColdFusion Developer that has started developing with jQuery and jQuery Mobile and am looking to getting into a cf framework ColdBox and a js framework KockoutJS. Now I am trying to wrap my head around if they can and how do they work together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine.

I use Backbone.js with a ColdFusion backend running the ColdBox framework.

You can return JSON directly from a Event Handler like this:

```
Event.renderData(data={'key'=value,'key2'=[1,2,3,4,'A','B','c']},type='JSON');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to look at it.  Because Knockout is a Javascript framework, it's easy to construct a working example using nothing more than HTML and Javascript.  You name your file with a htm or html extension, and server-side technology becomes irrelevant.  This holds true for any Javascript libraries or framework out there.

Now, you take that same HTML file (e.g. mypage.html), throw it into your Coldbox views folder, rename it with a .cfm extension, and it still does the same thing.  You can enhance it further with CF tags and script to output your data model, but in the end you're simply generating HTML and Javascript to send to the browser.